# How to retrieve a list of OAuth scopes for authorized Azure AD applications using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory

To clarify, I have limited knowledge about Azure AD. I'm trying to make a list of the OAuth scopes for applications that users have authorized. For example, when a user clicks on "Login with Microsoft," an application might request access to view the user's identity, read their email, or access their OneDrive files.

In Google Workspace, you can find this information using the following link: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens?hl=en

I would appreciate any guidance. I have created a Developer Account in Microsoft 365 and have used several applications, but I have not been able to find a user interface or method using the Microsoft Graph API to obtain this information.

Comment: [samples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-applications). we need an azure ad application in the tenant your app belongs to, then users in your tenant use their microsoft account`user@tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com` to sign in the app, then you can write code to call graph api to query user profile or other information, for example we can use this api to query [user profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). you can use different api to query different information.

Comment: you have a general question so I'm not sure how much you know and what is trouble you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions**:

[image]

In the **Azure Enterprise Applications**, search your application and copy the **`ObjectID`** of Service Principal:

[image]

To list the **OAuth scopes for authorized Azure AD applications**, try the below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/ServicePrincipalObjID/oauth2PermissionGrants
```

[image]

**Output:**

```json
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#oauth2PermissionGrants",
"value": [
{
"clientId": "xxxx",
"consentType": "AllPrincipals",
"id": "xxxx",
"principalId": null,
"resourceId": "xxxx",
"scope": "profile offline_access User.Read openid email"
}
]
}
```

> For example, when a user clicks on "Login with Microsoft," an application might request access to view the user's identity, read their email, or access their OneDrive files.

To achieve your scenario, create an **Azure AD Application and assign the required API permissions**:

[image]

To sign-in the user to the Application, **I generated authorization code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

The **auth code** got generated successfully like below:

[image]

By using the below parameters, I generated the **access token** like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, the **scopes** are like below:

[image]

By using the above access token, you can call the APIs like below:

To get the **signed-in user details**, I used below query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

You can configure the graph queries in your code and access them based on your requirement.